# Segmen-Anything-Modell (SAM): Remove purple backround

Tags: python, computer-vision

I copied a code from a youtube video (link: [Youtube-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdWwc_fw0yQ&t=728s)) that combines YOLO-Nas and SAM. This also works so far. I just want to generate a mask for the area inside the BoundingBox. However, the background is always displayed in purple and I can't get rid of it. I don't want to have a mask for the background. How can I set this up?

Here are excerpts from my code:

```
def show_mask(mask, ax):
    color = np.array([30/255, 144/255, 255/255, 0.6])
    h, w = mask.shape[-2:]
    mask_image = mask.reshape(h, w, 1) * color.reshape(1, 1, -1)
    ax.imshow(mask_image)

def show_points(coords, labels, ax, marker_size=375):
    pos_points = coords[labels==1]
    neg_points = coords[labels==0]
    ax.scatter(pos_points[:, 0], pos_points[:, 1], color='green', marker='*', s=marker_size, edgecolor='white', linewidth=1.25)
    ax.scatter(neg_points[:, 0], neg_points[:, 1], color='red', marker='*', s=marker_size, edgecolor='white', linewidth=1.25)

def show_box(box, ax):
    x0, y0 = box[0], box[1]
    w, h = box[2] - box[0], box[3] - box[1]
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x0, y0), w, h, edgecolor='green', facecolor=(0,0,0,0), lw=2))

def show_anns (anns):
  if len(anns) == 0:
    return
  sorted_anns = sorted(anns, key=(lambda x: x['area']), reverse=True)
  ax = plt.gca()
  ax. set_autoscale_on (False)
  polygons = []
  color = []
  for ann in sorted_anns:
    m = ann['segmentation']
    img = np.ones ((m.shape[0], m.shape[1], 3))
    color_mask = np.random.random((1, 3)).tolist()[0]
    for i in range (3):
      img[:,:, i] = color_mask[i]
    ax.imshow(np.dstack((img, m*0.35)))

import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from super_gradients.training import models
from segment_anything import sam_model_registry, SamPredictor
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image_path = "/content/Concrete-crack-images-from-a-METU-b-USU.png"
image = cv2.imread('/content/Concrete-crack-images-from-a-METU-b-USU.png')


#SAM Model for Masking
sam_checkpoint = CHECKPOINT_PATH_SAM
model_type = "vit_h"
device = "cuda"

sam = sam_model_registry[model_type](checkpoint= sam_checkpoint)
sam.to(device=device)

predictor = SamPredictor(sam)


predictor.set_image(image)

original_image = image.copy()

image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1)) #Transpose to match SAM input format
image = image / 255.0 # Normalize image values to [0,1]
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)

input_box = np.array(bboxes_xyxy[0])

if labels[0] == 0:
  #Predict mask using SAM
  masks, _, _ = predictor.predict(
      point_coords = None,
      point_labels = None,
      box = input_box[None, :],
      multimask_output = False,
  )

# Display the image with masks and bounding box
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) 


if labels[0] == 0:
  plt.imshow(masks[0], alpha=0.5)
plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle((input_box[0], input_box[1]), input_box[2] - input_box[0], input_box[3] - input_box[1],
                                   linewidth=2, edgecolor ="r", facecolor='none'))
plt.text(input_box[0], input_box[1] - 5, 'Crack', fontsize=12, color="r", backgroundcolor='w')
plt.axis('off')
#plt.savefig('output_folder/output3.png')
plt.show()
```